# adding LinearLayout to scrollview in android

Tags: android

Please help me friends. I am tried to draw pie chart in android. First i am adding this view to Linear Layout and then tried to add that Linear Layout to ScrollView. I need scroll view because my content is dynamically expandable. And then add that scroll layout to my parent relative layout. While adding Linear layout to parent program working fine. But while adding scrollview to parent it dispaly's nothing. My code is

```
RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);

values = calculateData(values);
MyGraphview graphview = new MyGraphview(this, values);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

ll.setOrientation(1);
ll.addView(graphview);
sv.addView(ll);     

r1.addView(sv);
```

note this friends.

```
ll.addView(graphview);
//sv.addView(ll);       

r1.addView(ll);
```

This is working fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure but try adding layout params while adding linearLayout to scrollview  sv.addView(ll,(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); and for the r1.addview() also

Comment: Did not working friend

Comment: make sure that type of layout out params is parent type.. i.e while adding ll to sv, layout params should be of SV

Comment: i have set `new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))` this only to all.

Comment: For scroll the view layout params should be like new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))   , Try remove layout params for all the views check if it works if not set corresponding layout params for the corresponding type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by overriding onMeasure method on on MyGraphView class. But now new problem arises that is the chart also scrolling like bubble scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define your layout in the layout xml?

Comment: I am going to draw chart. thats why i cant define it in the layout.